# node.js upload vs post for large data - Which is better option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am building a node.js website and the UI will allow user to upload a large csv file with many 1000's of rows...(atleast > 10k rows and 50 mb size)

This file need to be field validated and pre-processed (converted to JSON) before I store it in my database.

If I use the html file upload mechanism and do the "pre-processing" on the server, which is a for-loop, node.js event loop will be blocked. So, I tried using the HTML5 FileReader to read the file in client's browser and pre-process it to JSON.

Now I need to send this JSON data as a POST. How can POST it via AJAX without blocking node.js? Also as a secondary question how can I save this data as a file on server as chunks so server wont be loaded with 50 mb data...

Any advice on the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You can even process it on the fly if you stream it through node to your database server. This shouldn't block the event loop.

Comment: @Bergi - Could you please point me how to do that please?

Comment: Try any of [these](https://www.google.de/search?q=nodejs+csv+stream). Surely you'll also find a way to pipe your stream through something that serialises it to JSON step-by-step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar use-case. I solved it by first splitting the file into chunks. (define a chunk size of n lines) and adding it to a simple queue object.

Then use a recursive jQuery AJAX POST to submit each chunk from the queue until the queue is empty. This is similar to using BLOB api to chunk a file except we care about lines in CSV file rather than chunk size.

I have this on production uploading very large files and it works very fast, you can easily control cancel, pause, continue, progress etc...

Comment: thanks for your solution. I had kind of started working on this logic. Will post updates.